# How to show something on Incoming Call Screen

Tags: android

I am developing an  app that shows the location of the caller when an incoming call come on incoming call screen. I am succesfully fetching the location from my algorithm but I am not able to display it on Deafult Incoming Screen.

If i use A toast then it just appears for 1 or 2seconds, I want ihe information shoulkd appear till the call picked.

What should I use Toast, Notification or something , and how to do that.

In short how can I show something on Incoming Call Screen till the call picked up

```
       class IncomingCallREceiver extends BroadcastReciever
       {
               void onRecieve()
              {
                //     here I want to show the Information
               }
        }
```

Comment: The short answer is that you cannot show something inside of an activity that is not yours. So your only choices are Toast and Notification, unless you want to create an entire phone app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to override Android's call screen, and with good reason, things may get spoofed!

With that said, a Dialog would most likely be the best solution to showing something before the user picks up. The easiest way to make a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is with DialogFragments. However since Dialogs cannot be shown from receivers, you will need to start an Activity. So your `onReceive()` code should look something like this:

```
void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
          {
            Intent showDialogIntent = new Intent (context, DialogActivity.class);
            showDialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startIntent (showDialogIntent);               
          }
```

And then when your DialogActivity is started, it's `onCreate()` method would make the Dialog and show it to the user.